# Hadoop: JAVA JPS tool not working

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I have the Hadoop installed everything looks working fine, except jps.

every time run jps,(I have Oracle Java jdk1.8.0_31 installed) I get this:

```
The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

anyone can help?  really appreaciate.

here is my java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write "which java", you'll get the path to your java, and in the bin directory look for "jps".

If you find jps there then, perform the below step:

ln - s  /usr/bin/jps
OR
You can add bin directory to the class path